# Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services:[15.0.0, 16.0.0)

Tags: android

i use firebase and onesignal , but when opening project give me the error ,
i update build-tools , sdk tools and google play services.

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
>   Open File
> Show Details
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
>   Open File
> Show Details

build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven'

    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

}
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

build.gradle(app) :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'


repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.tethys.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    manifestPlaceholders = [
            onesignal_app_id               : '811bb48c-2350-455d-aa7d-63eea30e226e',
            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
            onesignal_google_project_number: '845923319180'
    ]

}
buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.5'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.afollestad:easyvideoplayer:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.3-beta'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.ss.bottomnavigation:bottomnavigation:1.5.2'
implementation project(':infinitescrollprovider')
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you post your app-level Gradle config?

Comment: yes , post edited

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to your root level `build.gradle` file like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do it like this if your version of Gradle plugin supports it:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```